# Move_base is stuck while status is ACTIVE

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am driving around my robot and testing the move_base node. It moves around fairly well as long as I order goal positions that the robot can reach. The problem is:

when I order a goal position that the robot can not reach (due to a small door for example) the status of that goal remains ACTIVE forever but the robot does not move. If I order a new goal, the status of the new goal is PENDING but it never becomes ACTIVE because the first order is still ACTIVE (and will be like that forever). If I keep sending new goal positions, the old ones which are PENDING are discarded, and the new ones are introduced as PENDING as well.

How should I proceed in order to regain control over my robot?
Thanks for your tips and comments!

---

EDIT-1 (answer to 1st comment): the way I communicate with the move_base node is by pusblishing and subscribing to its topics:
/move_base/status provides me with the status of every goal
/move_base_simple/goal  accepts goal positions
In order to learn how the navigation stack works I followed this tutorial (it was months ago, now parameters are tunned to fit my needs):
http://www.ist.tugraz.at/robotics/bin/view/Main/Poineer_pathplanning

---

EDIT-2: I checked the log of move_base node and this is what happens:
( WAR] (1358262472.775372377, 81184.500000000]: Clearing costmap to unstuck robot.
( WARN] (1358262472.879543309, 81184.600000000]: Rotate recovery behavior started.
(but not recovery behaviour is started)

Moreover, If I request to cencel all the current goals of move_base (publishing a cancel with all goal_ids), then the status of the stuck goal changes from ACTIVE to PREEMPTING and eventually to PREEMPTED. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52279/move_base-is-stuck-while-status-is-active/) by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 483 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-01-15**:
Which tutorial did you use to set things up? And how are you sending the goals?

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-01-15**:
I have edited my question to include that information, thanks for your time!

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-25**:
Did some solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the 'solution':
First, I read about the move_base having problems when it runs for long (?), or when restarting it without restarting roscore (?), or something similar I can't remember...,

Therefore, the solution is to just **restart everything**. The navigation stack now works ok!

---

Originally posted by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) with karma: 483 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-04**:
Has anyone found a permanent fix to the problem ? Thank you.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-25**:
It doesn't work for me

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-08-25**:
Maybe post details to your problem that are different from this one ?